# How to group by a field and return list of other field?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with columns id, user
I want to group by column id and show a list of users (comma separated) for each id.

In the final output I need to display:

```
user joe - id 1
users jim, mark, john - id 2
user dave - id 3
....
```

I'm getting error "Cardinality violation: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row" if I try this:

```
SELECT id, (SELECT distinct(user) FROM mytable b where a.id = b.id)
FROM mytable a
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using MySQL, there is a built-in function for that which is the **[GROUP_CONCAT](http://mahmudahsan.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/mysql-the-group_concat-function/)** function. For example, you have a records like this:

```
ID      User
1       Joe
2       Jim
2       Mark
2       John
3       Dave
```

If you try to run this query:

```
SELECT ID, GROUP_CONCAT(User) Users
FROM tableName
GROUP BY ID
```

you will then have a result like this:

```
ID         Users
1          Joe
2          Jim, Mark, John
3          Dave
```

Comment: perfect! Thanks. I've used that one before, just couldn't remember at all. I added a distinct() inside the group_concat() to only get unique records!

Comment: I've selected yours as the correct answer, duskwuff beat you too eat because he had a shorter answer (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) I believe your started sooner and the examples will be helpful for others. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is the `GROUP_CONCAT` aggregate function:

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(user) FROM table GROUP BY id
```